# Running wire ahead of actual need to use it?

Tags: wiring

I just wired for a new oven and microwave. 2 30A circuits FWIW.

Now, my basement ceiling is ripped open as is the garage wall behind my kitchen.

Before I repair the drywall in both places, I'm pondering -

Running 8/3 wire (for 40A 220V power) to a box in the garage and another box in the basement, both just covered. This would seem to be enough to handle more than what I'd need if/when I got an electric car. 40A vs the 32A I'm seeing for typical car chargers.

I am asking - aside from the question of whether it will ever be used, is there a downside to this? The 50 ft I'd need is about $250, and small compared to the time I'll spend patching the drywall.

Comment: Are you asking about using bigger wire than needed on a circuit that exists, or running spare extra wire just in case you decide to set up another circuit one day?

Comment: I'm asking to confirm the concept is sound, i.e. running wire with no immediate need. I will update title question. I understand current will have a 'minimum' gauge requirement, but a bit bigger shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I doubt there's any real downside apart from the cost of the wire, the work to install it, and the possibility of confusing yourself or your electrician in the future. Better wait for someone who knows what they're doing to answer, though.

Comment: To avoid confusion for future electrical work, be sure to label any unused wires as such, with a potential mark for what the wire is intended for. For example, your 40A wiring could be labelled as "EV charge circuit(unused)" on the main panel tags, or have a wire tag of some sort to that effect. It would certainly be useful to install the wiring now if you do plan on having an EV charger there in the future.

Comment: The only downside is wasting money for something that might never be.  If you have a five year plan now(saving for an EV) go for it.  A ten/fifteen year plan maybe wait and see.

Comment: Of course, timing is of the essence, unfortunately, your is bad. Wiring prices are astronomical these days! Your $250 of wiring now was probably $100 12 months ago. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic premise is OK, but a few things to consider:

- EV circuit size

First of all, the 32A is *not* a standard circuit size. It is **80%** of a standard circuit size, 40A. A typical charger will use 32A but require a 40A circuit. That's the way these things work.

But you may decide in the future that you want a **bigger** circuit. Perhaps 60A (48A charge rate). The wire you put in for 40A will not be able to handle 60A.

- Other circuits

Most people never need anything in their garage besides convenience receptacles (e.g., occasional tool use, tool chargers, radio, etc.), lighting, a garage door opener and EV charging. Convenience receptacles and lighting are normally included in the initial construction and you are already taking care of EV charging. However, a small but not insignificant group of people want to make a "shop" in their garage - e.g., *lots* of tools, welder, dust collector, etc. For those people, a subpanel makes the most sense.

- Wire type

Copper is the gold standard for home wiring. But aluminum can be a *lot* cheaper, and while aluminum can be a concern with individual receptacles (though some are compatible, especially in larger sizes), breaker panels handle aluminum with no problem at all.

#### Subpanel

So putting it all together and planning for the future, the best choice may be to install a *subpanel* instead of wiring for an individual circuit. Put in *big* aluminum wiring. Aluminum wiring is typically one physical size larger to get the same current carrying capacity as copper, but it is a *lot* cheaper.

For example, you could put in 2 AWG aluminum wire and a 90A breaker for a feed to a nice big subpanel. In a quick (retail online pricing) search, I found $1.50/foot for 2/2/2/4 cable vs. $5.38/foot for 8/3 copper Romex cable, and the 8/3 can only handle 40A.

You can wait on actually installing the subpanel, or install it now and add breakers/circuits later. You can put in a subpanel that is "100A" or "150A" or whatever, because the only value that really matters is 90A *breaker in the main panel*. Then you are set for a 40A (32A charge rate) or 60A (48A charge rate) EV, power tools, etc. in the future. **Actually, the $150 you just saved on wire will pay for the subpanel and a bunch of breakers!**

Comment: 6/3 Romex, it is. (Basement already has shop. Garage is only 2 cars, so not looking to add a subpanel.) I appreciate the detailed response.

Comment: Your money, your choice. But consider that with the right receptacle (i.e., compatible with copper and aluminum) you can still use big aluminum wire, save a bunch of money and have the *option* of a subpanel later.

Comment: And a sub panel option in the garage _could_ add to resale value.

Comment: @FreeMan - I realize this is going off on a tangent, for the fact that my basement is set up with a workshop now, a 220 outlet to run a tablesaw, and sliding doors to walk out with the ability to bring stuff in and out to the workshop. What would the buyer do with a sub panel in the garage? Obviously, I am being dense and without imagination. That is why I visit, and keep an open mind.

Comment: If you really have no need for other "stuff" in a garage, then a subpanel is not needed. But in that case, I would **still go with aluminum wiring** as it will save a bunch of money. In other words, 2/2/2/4 aluminum cable to a 40A breaker on one end and 40A (32A) charger in the garage. That is cheaper than 8/3 or 6/3 copper and allows you to later bump to 60A **or** to a 90A-fed subpanel or whatever. Subpanel allows 2 chargers, tools, whatever...

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica oh, sure, rub it in! Options are always good. As manassehkats said, it gives you options for the future. It's far less expensive to put the wire in place now that will support a panel later than to open everything up when that new "gotta have it" thing comes along that you don't have a chance of thinking of today. Just think - 10 years ago, almost _nobody_ was thinking about putting an EV charger in their garage...

Comment: @JTP  You're falling into the logical trap of "my masterwork design is *all I will ever need*, and you've already forgotten the dust collector!  Or compressor, welder, larger EVSE than 32A, you name it.  You never know.  As you say, it's cheap to put stuff in right now.  You know what's even cheaper? 24-space panels with 2-2-2-4 Al feeder (90A). *The larger subpanel will more than pay for the feeder because 2-2-2-4 is way cheaper than 6NM*.

Comment: Not at all. Maybe. I am having a tough time thinking that a buyer would actually give a car space to have a workshop in the garage when we have nearly a 400 square-foot workshop in a comfortable basement. I understand that anything is possible. And there is always the chance the next owner will not care at all. About the workshop, the gym, or the dance studio I built for my daughter. Actually sad to think about this future possibility.

Comment: @FreeMan - after reading everything here, the thing that feels that makes the most sense? To simply leave an access panel in both the garage in the basement ceiling. In the future, I would be able to put any wire from the garage all the way to the panel. And I can stop obsessing about it now.

Comment: Run conduit ([see my answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/237238/34147)) to make it easier to get the updated wiring from one access panel to the next. Yeah... None of us know what super cool thing is coming next that's going to need power, and there's no telling what the next owner will want to do - assuming you sell before you die :)

Comment: @JTP the "killer app" that drives me to 90A cable and a subpanel is future EV charging. The current state of the art is one 80A circuit being "smartly shared" by 2-3 EVSEs with that feature.  They dynamically split the (64A actual) based on the cars they are charging right now.  EV#1 says "hey I am at my tail charge, only need 8A" it tells the other 2 cars "take 28A".  Also larger charge rates WILL happen, EVs are not done evolving. Not everyone can drive a small sedan. Tradesmen need their trucks, and you won't be charging a Transit van at 32A lol.

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet may be to run *conduit* to a location where you can install a panel as in [manassenhkatz' answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/237237/34147). Just install a big pipe and leave it empty for now.

Later when the need arises, you can install one outlet (at the conduit termination point or somewhere else) on an appropriately sized breaker, multiple outlets on multiple breakers (up to the conduit fill limits), or feeder wire to a panel with an appropriate breaker in the main panel.

Comment: This removes the guesswork of what size wire to run.

Answer (score 2):

### Range/oven

Microwaves don't need 30A circuits.  However, separates range and oven need dual 30A circuits and sometimes 30/40.   For best versatility, run a 30 and a 50 to the range/oven area.

#8 copper or #6 aluminum are good for 50A if they are *not* NM or UF types (the two cursed types of cable), and if in conduit they are alone.

### The garage

I would never spend $250 on 50' of any type of cable, that's just nuts.

But that's just your automatic "go-to", you use #14 copper NM for 15A circuits, #12 copper NM for 20A circuits, so you figure for bigger circuits just keep going on like that, nevermind the price going up exponentially and only getting NM or UF for your dollar.

Here's what I would spend.

- about $70 for a 24-space main-breaker panel, probably 200A main breaker (who cares).
- $65 normally, maybe $100 today, for 2-2-2-4 MH or USE aluminum feeder cable of a type allowed in my location.  That is 90A feeder.
- $10 for a 60A supply breaker in the main panel
- whatever for short cables and smaller breakers to serve today's loads

All that is cheaper than *your cable alone*.

That is just *my* automatic "go-to"... *my I don't want to plan the future loads, I just want to **cover all bases** with commodity gear at a good price point*. Whatever you plan to do in that garage, that panel has got your needs covered.

Nobody would ever say "oh, the future definitely will not include any electric stuff we don't already know about".

The feeder is actually good to 90A and you can enlarge to a 90A breaker at your leisure.  I just went 60A because it's the cheapest breaker that will accept wires that large.

It's so cheap and easy, why not do it? Clearly you are ready to plop down well over $250.   If you want to up-spend on this deal, get the 90A breaker right out of the chute, or go with 1/0 or 2/0 feeder and run 125A.

Comment: Oven project done. It's 2 units, installed one over the other. The manufacturer calls "microwave" a "speed oven", as it has a cyclotron but also the features of a convection oven. Both have a 220 plug, and specify needing 30A breakers. I realize the future-proofing I was hoping for isn't the tradeoff I thought. i.e. happy to toss $250 away if I don't get an EV, but I'll have the box ready if I do." But from answers, I may still wind up feeling I ran too small a circuit.  (cont)

Comment: On a side note - We had our house built in 1996. At the time, I had the electrician run 2 Cat 5 cables to every phone jack in the house. A few years ago, I updated my internet to 200Mbs service, got the new modem,  newer routers, etc. I was only getting 100Mbs speed test, and same within my home. I found the guy used 4 wire ethernet configuration, and other 4 wires for 2 phone lines. After a few weekends of sitting on floor rewiring, I got full speed.   This was my best "future-proofing" experience.

Comment: @JTP Yup, conduit is absolutely the way to go. EMT isn't bad to work with once you get the hang of it.  (key: don't even attempt compound curves; use couplers).  As for copper, I watch a lot of Youtube. So far I've seen 2 off-grid electric projects fail because when confronted with the cost of copper wire,  both of them balked and went with #10 instead of the *needed* #4Cu (or #2Al but they didn't know that).  The projects failed due to voltage drop, no surprise.   *Note that #10 Cu is about the same price as #2 Al*.